# Как отличить переменную от метода в С#?

Tags: c#, переменные, методы

Изучаю основы. Вычисление объема сферы, фрагмент кода.

```
public double sqrSphere()
{
    return 4 * Math.PI * r * r;
}

public void writeResult()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Вычислить площадь или объем? s/v:");
    s = Console.ReadLine();
    s = s.ToLower();
    if (s == "s")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Площадь шара равна {0:#.###}", sqrSphere());
        return;
    }
}
```

Вопросы:

```
public double sqrSphere()
```

sqrSphere() это метод или переменная? Если метод, то как можно сделать такой вывод? По наличию параметров после идентефикатора? Раньше знал о переменных double, а здесь это часть метода?

```
Console.WriteLine("Площадь шара равна {0:#.###}", sqrSphere());
```

Здесь выводится значение sqrSphere() . Получается, sqrSphere() - переменная?
Совсем запутался, простите нуба.

P.S.  Всем спасибо за ответы. Есть недостаток знаний о возвращаемых типах и методах в целом, постигаю азы.

Comment: для площади поверхности используйте название `Area` или `SurfaceArea`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Любой метод имеет *сигнатуру* (собственное имя + список формальных параметров), тип возвращаемого значения, а так же возможно и различные модификаторы.

`public double sqrSphere()` - открытый **метод** без параметров, возвращающий значение типа double.

В этой строке

```
Console.WriteLine("Площадь шара равна {0:#.###}", sqrSphere());
```

сначала вычисляется результат выполнения метода, а потом этот результат подставляется в форматную строку. За ходом исполнения программы вы можете наблюдать в отладчике.

Comment: Если быть совсем точным, то сначала в стек помещается форматная строка, затем идет вызов sqrSphere(), результат которого помещается в стек, и делается boxing и затем делается вызов Console.WriteLine

Comment: @AlexanderEgorov знание низкоуровневой реализации безусловно важно для написания эффективного кода, но это уже следующая ступенька, для общего понимания что делает программа достаточно и более простого объяснения приведенного в ответе.

Comment: @ rdorn Я с вами полностью согласен

Answer (score 6):

небольшое дополнение к уже имеющимся правильным ответам.

Действительно иногда бывает трудно только по внешнему виду отличить переменную от свойства, метода или даже типа. Особенно если код чужой, мудреный и открыт в блокноте без подсветки синтаксиса. Поэтому соглашения об именовании становятся еще более актуальными. Понятно что почти у каждой команды есть свои соглашения (camelCase, PascalCase, венгерская нотация и т.д. останется за кадром, религиозные вопросы не трогаю принципиально =)), но некоторые из них можно считать общепринятыми. Ниже примерный список таких соглашений для пользовательских идентификаторов:

- длина имени должна быть необходимой и достаточной для однозначного понимания его смысла. Иначе говоря, не экономьте символы в ущерб понятности названия, но и не растекайтесь мыслью. Если есть общепринятая (или принятая в вашей команде) аббревиатура (usb, wcf и т.д.), ее можно и нужно использовать, но изобретать что-то свое только для уменьшения длины имени не стоит без крайней необходимости.
- имя поля или свойства является существительным простым `Length`, `Size` либо составным (да простят меня лингвисты за излишнее упрощение) `CurrentTime`, `CustomerList`.
- Для логических полей и свойств допустимо использовать вопросительную форму (IsActive, HasValue).
- имя метода является глаголом `Count()`, `Sort()` или начинается с глагола `GetValue()`, `PerformAction()`.

Даже этих простых правил именования, не вдаваясь в прочие аспекты Code Conventions, будет вполне достаточно, чтобы относительно комфортно читать код не разыскивая объявление сущности для опознания каждого нового идентификатора.

Answer (score 3):

Как выглядит разница:

```
    //Метод
    public double Var1()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    //Свойство
    public double Var2 { get { return _var3; } set { _var3 = value; } }

    //Переменная / поле
    public double _var3 = 0;
```

> Раньше знал о переменных double, а здесь это часть метода?

В данном случае это не часть метода, а тип возвращаемого значения этим методом.

А иногда бывает так:

```
    public double sqrSphere()
    {
        return 4 * Math.PI * r * r;
    }

    public void Print (string str, Func<double> func)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(str, func());
    }
    public void writeResult()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Вычислить площадь или объем? s/v:");
        s = Console.ReadLine();
        s = s.ToLower();
        if (s == "s")
        {
            Print("Площадь шара равна {0:#.###}", sqrSphere);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Немного глупый пример на коленке, но тут можно увидеть что метод `sqrSphere` в метод `Print` передается по виду совсем как переменная/поле/метод и для того, что бы выяснить что перед нами нужно знать сигнатуру метода `Print` и все станет ясно.

Answer (score 0):

Ну и совсем уж простейшая деталь: метод без "()" не вызвать. Если видишь имя без "()" - значит, это поле.
`public double sqrSphere()` - а если анализировать эту строку, то `public` - идентификатор доступа, `double` - тип, возвращаемый методом, `sqrSphere` - имя метода. Ну и "()" для принимаемых аргументов.

Comment: Ну это по факту не всегда так. Например: `Func<double> f = sqrSphere;`.

Comment: Или так: `Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles("Temp"), File.Delete);`  `File.Delete` - это метод.

Comment: Вы меня убедили, господа))

Answer (score 0):

Может быть будет понятнее то что в IL коде получается при выводе строчки в консоль?

`IL_0029: ldstr "Площадь шара равна {0:#.###}"
IL_002e: call float64 YourNameSpace.YourClass::'sqrSphere'()
IL_0033: box [mscorlib]System.Double
IL_0038: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string, object)`

call говорит о том что это вызов метода. для переменных только загрузка (команды начинающиеся с ld)

Comment: занятно. Получается что вариант формирования строки через StringBuilder единственный, который не использует боксинг. Интерполяция тоже работает с боксингом, проверил. Учтемс